# How to prove every rational function is infinitely differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In my mind, every rational function is definitely infinitely differentiable. I think I can use the formula $(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})^{'} = \frac{f^{'}(x)g(x)-g^{'}(x)f(x)}{g^2(x)}$, but I don't know how can I show it in an exact way...

Comment: Yes, you use the quotient rule to show that the derivative of a rational function is another rational function; in particular, it exists (at all points where $g(x) \neq 0$). Then by induction all derivatives exist (at all points where $g(x) \neq 0$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I've thought of using induction, but I have no idea how does this induction should work...

Comment: You let $P(n)$ be the statement that the $n^{th}$ derivative exists. A function is infinitely differentiable iff $P(n)$ is true for all $n$. So you prove it by induction: show that $P(0)$ is true, then show that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$. Yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A hint for an alternative solution**

Every rational function has a unique decomposition of the form $$P(x)+\sum_{1\le k\le n}\dfrac{\lambda_k}{(x-a_k)^{n_k}}$$ where $P$ is a polynomial (possibly zero) while $\lambda_k\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}, a_k\in\mathbb{C},$ and $n_k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ for all $k=1, 2,\cdots, n.$

For example $$\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}=\dfrac{i}{2(x+i)}-\dfrac{i}{2(x-i)}.$$